# Most efficient RowScan of very large Bigtable table

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I am looking for the fastest way to perform a row scan of very large Bigtable tables using the latest JAVA API. I only need to scan based on partial row values (no column/column family information needed). The row values are well distributed and Bigtable's lexicographic sorting works well for this use case.

There are a lot of answers out there on this topic throughout the years, but some of them are outdated for older versions and some of them seem to be HBase-specific, or shell-specific. I need specifically for Cloud Bigtable and for the latest versions of JAVA API.

For now, based on my own testing, I see this as the best approach:

```
Scan s = new Scan();
s.setStartRow(startRowKey); // this can also be passed to constructor
s.setStopRow(stopRowKey); // this can also be passed to constructor
s.setRowPrefixFilter(key.getBytes());
s.setFilter(new PageFilter(MaxResult));
s.setFilter(new KeyOnlyFilter());
```

But my questions are:

1: Is there something I'm not aware of I should be doing to improve the    speed?

2: Is there a better way to limit the results other than       through `PageFilter()`?  I.e. how can I say "return max 25 rows"

3: what is the difference between      `scan.setFilter(new PrefixFilter(rowKey))` and       `scan.setRowPrefixFilter(rowKey)`

4: the advantage of putting the      `startRow` parameter for the scan is **very clear**, but is there any       advantage (or disadvantage) to putting the `endRow` parameter as       well? particularly if you are providing the `PageSize()` or another     limit measur

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your filters are clobbering each other (the `KeyOnlyFilter` will overwrite the `PageFilter`, you should wrap them in a `MUST_PASS_ALL` `FilterList`.

1. Other then the bug I mentioned above, I can't think of any other optimizations.
2. I don't believe the HBase API provides another way to specify the row limit.
3. In your case not much. Main reason to use a `PrefilterFilter` is to be able to chain it together with other filters in a `FilterList`.
4. There is definitely no downside to adding an `endRow`, but at the same time, I don't think there is much gain either.

Comment: Thanks for the answers to all points. I wasn't aware of the need for the FilterList. Frankly now that I've added it, I don't see much of a difference performance-wise using the FilterList vs. setting them one-by-one. But it's good to know there might be something buggy happening in the background if that's not done...